# Overwriting a list doesn´t work (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, overwrite, node.js-fs

I have a form in the frontend which transfers data. In the backend I have an app.js and an itemList.js. I would like to overwrite or update the itemList.js with the transferred data. Through the console.log I see that the incoming data is correct. I also get the message 'item editing successfully' in the frontend only in the browser console I get the error message error editing item. can anyone help me and tell me what's wrong?

I would like to find the error and know how to overwrite the list correctly
this is my code in the app.js:

```
app.post('/edit', (req, res) => { 
    const itemsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'itemList.js');
    const itemList = require('./itemList');
  
    const itemIndex = itemList.findIndex(item => item.id === req.body.selectid);
  
    console.log(req.body);

    if (itemIndex !== -1) {
        itemList[itemIndex].name = req.body.addname;
        itemList[itemIndex].abbreviation = req.body.abbreviation;
        itemList[itemIndex].urlCM = req.body.urlCM;
        itemList[itemIndex].urlTcg = req.body.urlTCG;
        itemList[itemIndex].trader = {
          urlTraderENG: req.body.urlTraderENG,
          urlTraderGER: req.body.urlTraderGER
        };
        itemList[itemIndex].miracle = {
          urlMiracleENG: req.body.urlMiracleENG,
          urlMiracleGER: req.body.urlMiracleGER
        };
        itemList[itemIndex].jke = {
          urljkeENG: req.body.urlJkeENG,
          urljkeGER: req.body.urlJkeGER
        };
    
        fs.writeFileSync(
          itemsPath,
          `const items = ${JSON.stringify(itemList, null, 4)}; \nmodule.exports = items;\n`
        )
        res.send('Item editing successfully');
        console.log('item editing successfully');
      } else {
        res.send('Error editing item');
        console.log('error editing item');
      }
});
```

my itemList.js is structured like this:

```
//...
{
        "id": 56,
        "name": "test",
        "abbreviation": "t",
        "urlCM": "testurl",
        "urlTcg": "",
        "trader": {
            "urlTraderENG": "",
            "urlTraderGER": ""
        },
        "miracle": {
            "urlMiracleENG": "",
            "urlMiracleGER": ""
        },
        "jke": {
            "urljkeENG": "",
            "urljkeGER": ""
        }
    }
//...
```

Can someone help me or find the solution? :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have to parse the id:

```js
const itemIndex = itemList.findIndex(item => item.id === parseInt(req.body.selectid));
```